# Launch the Swift screen from Flutter: Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I want to open the Swift screen from Flutter, but an error occurs and I can't open it.
I am using FirebaseAnalytics in Swift screen.

```
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC0D16DecodingStrategyO6base64yA2EmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC19KeyDecodingStrategyO14useDefaultKeysyA2EmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC19keyDecodingStrategyAC03KeygH0OvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC20DateDecodingStrategyO6customyAE10Foundation0F0Vs0E0_pKccAEmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC20dataDecodingStrategyAC0dgH0OvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC20dateDecodingStrategyAC04DategH0OvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC23passthroughTypeResolverAA026StructureCodingPassthroughgH0_pXpvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC34NonConformingFloatDecodingStrategyO5throwyA2EmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC34nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategyAC03NonghiJ0OvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC6decode_4fromxxm_yptKSeRzlFTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC8userInfoSDys010CodingUserG3KeyVypGvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataEncoderC0D16EncodingStrategyO6base64yA2EmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataEncoderC19KeyEncodingStrategyO14useDefaultKeysyA2EmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataEncoderC19keyEncodingStrategyAC03KeygH0OvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataEncoderC20DateEncodingStrategyO6customyAEy10Foundation0F0V_s0E0_ptKccAEmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataEncoderC20dataEncodingStrategyAC0dgH0OvsTj
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is documented on GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9806

The root of the issue is `firebase_core_platform_interface` version `4.5.2` introducing breaking changes and the other firebase packages use `firebase_core_platform_interface` as a package dependency and are set to update minor version automatically and this minor version contained a breaking change.

Some people seem to have luck with overriding a sub-dependency in pubspec.yaml
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9806#issuecomment-1294532006

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

You also might need to rollback/upgrade Firebase dependencies to line up with this change if you happen to use them

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9806#issuecomment-1294545363

```
firebase_auth: 4.1.0
firebase_core: 2.1.1
firebase_dynamic_links: 5.0.3
cloud_firestore: 4.0.3
firebase_storage: 11.0.3
firebase_messaging: 14.0.3
cloud_functions: 4.0.3
```

Following making these changes you can start fresh by running
`flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

Random things I had to change to get it to work in addition to above was update Podfile to `platform :ios, '13.0'` and removed `pod 'FirebaseFirestore'`
And I had to set the Firebase dependencies to these specific versions instead

```
firebase_core: 2.1.0
firebase_auth: 4.0.2
cloud_firestore: 4.0.2
cloud_functions: 4.0.2
firebase_storage: 11.0.2
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the Firebase dependencies and it worked.
10.0.0 → 9.6.0

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '9.6.0'
```

```
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.3
  cloud_functions: ^3.3.3
  firebase_analytics: ^9.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.6.2
  firebase_core: ^1.20.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.8.6
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.3.3
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.4
  firebase_remote_config: ^2.0.13
```